# How do I return a different ActionResult from my controller that takes arguments?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Controller` with some actions on it as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateModel model)
{
    if (model.SelectedCustomers.Count > 0 &&
        model.SelectedVersions.Count > 0 &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ScriptName) &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ScriptText))
    {

        Script script;
        ...save to database...
        return Edit(script.Id);   //<---------Return other view here
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? scriptId)
{
    return View();
}
```

After the `Create` action runs, and saves my model to the database successfully, I want to send the user to the `Edit` view for the newly created script.  When I use the code above, specifically `return Edit(script.Id);` it just sends the user back to the `Create` view instead of the `Edit` view.  When the user navigates to the `Edit` action directly, or through the result of an `Html.ActionLink` pointed at `Edit` everything works correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `RedirectToAction("Edit", new {scriptId = script.Id})`

Comment: `View` has a _default_ meaning (it's a method either in the `Controller` base class or an extension method).  If you want to alter which view is returned, then look at the parameters that method accepts (like view name).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it does:

```
return Edit(script.Id)
```

It's not actually telling the framework to go to that action.  It's just returning the return value of that *method*.  Purely a C# concern before any components of the ASP.NET MVC Framework are involved at all.  And what is that return value:

```
return View()
```

So the former is *really* functionally the same thing as the latter.  And any time you use `return View()` in ASP.NET MVC, the framework will determine that view by examining the action *currently being called*, which in this case is `Create`.

What you want isn't to return the `Edit` view (even if you do, in this case, the user is still on the `Create` *URL*, which will cause confusion).  What you want is to return a redirect to tell the *client* to *request* that next action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { scriptId = script.Id });
```

Comment: Ahh, so the result of `View()` is determined by the way the controller was *originally* called, not by the `ActionMethod` that actually calls `View()`.  The behavior I was seeing makes sense now. Thank you for the in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can always call `RedirectToAction` and return that action result. That will inform the browser to redirect to the different action.

I think you will need something like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { scriptId = script.Id });
```

Calling `Edit` directly is no different than calling a method.

Comment: How do I send arguments that way?

Answer (score 2):

You can do with this `RedirecToAction` with input parameters.

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", new { id = 12 });
```

In Your Case:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { scriptId = script.Id });
```

Comment: It's `scriptId` not `id`

Comment: Yes, Added your scenario.